# Sqoop - Binding to YARN queues

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, hadoop-yarn, sqoop2

So with mapreduce v2 you can use binding to certain YARN queues to manage resources and prioritization.
Basically by using

"hadoop jar /xyz.jar -D mapreduce.job.queuename=QUEUE1 /input /output" which works perfectly.

How can integrate Yarn queue binding with Sqoop when you run a sqoop query?

ie. sqoop import \ --connect 'jdbc://server' \ --target-dir \ and what ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the same method for Sqoop as well i.e

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=NameOfTheQueue\ --connect 'jdbc://server' \ --target-dir \
```

Note that, the mapreduce.job.queuename parameter should be used after the import but before the connect or other options.