# Does Sqoop support capacity scheduler queues?

Tags: sqoop

Is it possible to specify the capacity scheduler queue name while doing `sqoop import`?

Comment: Why don't you **search** for the answer?? cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607451/sqoop-binding-to-yarn-queues

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Got it. Thanks! Actually I had searched, but I did not get that page. I was searching for "capacity queue+sqoop" not "yarn queue+sqoop", might be that was the reason.